# How can I move the option box to the right using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I move the option box to the right using CSS?
When the dropdown is pressed, I want a box of options to be shown on the right. What should I do?

```css
.input{
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    border: 3px solid #0026ff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>From</h1>
        </br>
        <div class="center">
            <input class="input" list="station" placeholder="Start typing...">
                <datalist class="list" id="station">
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                </datalist>
        </div>
        </br>
        <h1>To</h1>
        </br>
        <div class="center">
            <input class="input" list="station" placeholder="Start typing...">
                <datalist class="list" id="station">
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                </datalist>
        </div>
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. Use margin, padding, flexbox options, etc. Also, your syntax is faulty for those. Slashes aren't necessary, but they'd go before the closing angle bracket, if anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to change the direction to `rtl` for those elements. A possible drawback is that it moves the arrow icon to the left. You can set opacity to zero for Webkit browsers to hide it, though.

```css
.input {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 3px solid #0026ff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>From</h1>

<div class="center" dir="rtl">
  <input class="input" list="station" placeholder="Start typing...">
  <datalist class="list" id="station">
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                </datalist>
</div>

<h1>To</h1>

<div class="center" dir="rtl">
  <input class="input" list="station" placeholder="Start typing...">
  <datalist class="list" id="station">
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                    <option>c</option>
                </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see the arrow button ?

Comment: To quote myself, "You can set opacity to zero for Webkit browsers, though."